# How to force implicit conversion in polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please consider this example,
how do we force implicit conversion in function whose second parameter is pointer to member function.
casting explicitly in argument list of function is not what I want to achive wright now.
Instead I would like that compiler somehow do that like it does with FIRST parameter...

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = 0 {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void f(){}
};

typedef void(Base::*polymorph)();

// how do I force IMPLICIT conversion here: EDIT: (polymorph type work only for polymorph pointer type no conversion)
void func(Base* arg1, polymorph arg2) // void* arg2, (void*) arg2 etc...  dosn't work
{
    polymorph temp = reinterpret_cast<polymorph>(arg2); // to achive this
}

int main()
{
    Derived* test = new Derived;
    // first parameter work but another gives an error
    func(test, &Derived::f); // BY NOT CHANGING THIS!
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it just can't be done. In func all you know (statically) that you are dealing with a Base object, and it would be unsafe to pretend that any Base object has that method. - Also, just because there is a pointer involved, it doesn't mean you have to use `new/delete`: `Derived test; func(&test, &Derived::f);`

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please explain it.

Comment: I want to be able to pas a pointer to member method of what ever type to the function argument which takes pointer-to-member argument. in my example function should take "polimorph" type but it wont.

Comment: If that's what you want, just make it a template: template <class T> void func(Base*, void(T::*)());` But the question is still, what you are going to do with the function pointer.

Comment: Yeah, Template is good!, I've allready considered that. I was just currious if there is some other way. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clean as it gets.  Code below. But I have no idea who's "this" pointer is going to be referenced when "temp" actually gets invoked.

```
typedef void(Base::*polymorph)(); 

void func(Base* arg1, polymorph arg2)
{ 
    polymorph temp = arg2;
} 


int main() 
{ 
    Derived* test = new Derived; 
    // first parameter work but another gives an error 
    func(test, static_cast<polymorph>(&Derived::f)); 
    delete test; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for effort selbie, but second parameter is being converted explicitliy using static_cast but not implicitly as I intended. I wanted to do that in function main without casting operator. instead casting operator should be used somewere else. but that isn't possible isn it ?

Comment: @codekiddy - It's for the same reasons you can't implicitly cast a pointer to a base class to a pointer to a derived class.  Besides that, how is it possibly safe to invoke Derived::f via "temp"?  What object is going to invoke temp and what is its type? If the answer is "an instance of Base", then it is a big leap to assume type safety. Let me ask this: "What are you really trying to anyway?" If someone on my team was attempting to something screwy with pointer to member functions, we'd probably whiteboard a better design together involving interfaces and virtual methods.

Comment: what ever I was trying doesn't metter any more cos I've give up. thanks for your time!