# C++ polymorphic cloning: How to obtain a Derived pointer from a Base pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, cloning, covariant-return-types

This is already several posts that I sent about this subjet and I apologize if this bothers some of you. After playing around several days and trying different alternatives (patterns) I came up with the following conclusions, which allows me to better formulate my question.

I have a vector of `Base *` and there are various `Derived<T>` classes that derive from Base. The different class parameters T are declared at the beginning with a forward declaration. What I need is to take a pair of objects from this `vector<Base *>` and apply a `function(Derived<T1> obj1, Derived<T2> obj2)` using templates in order to do some kind of double dispatch. However, I am unable to convert a pointer-to-Base to a pointer-to-Derived when I take an element from the vector. Thus, I cannot use `function(Derived<T1> obj1, Derived<T2> obj2)`.

Of course, this could be simply achieved using `dynamic_cast<Derived<T> *>(base_ptr)`. However, this is not what I want since to do this, one must know T in advance, which is not the case here. I must be able to select whatever elements from the vector, without knowing their `Derived<T>` type.

Therefore, I tried polymorphic cloning. Although it uses covariant return types, unfortunately, it did not work. The reason, as explained by different people in SO, and according to the C++ standard, is that at compile time, the compiler still does not know the complete type of the object. Thus, although one expects that the clone() should return a `Derived<T> *`, it returns a `Base *`.

The few next lines of code express what I mean.
In general, the polymorphic cloning is used in the following case:

```
Base *b1 = new Derived;
Base *b2;
b2 = b1->clone();
```

This is not what I want. What I need is a pointer-to-Derived:

```
Base *b1 = new Derived;
Derived *d1;
d1 = b1->clone(); // This is what I want, but it fails.
```

Here, the compiler complains saying that an object of type `Base *` cannot be assigned to an object of type `Derived *`. Hence, I cannot use `*d1` in `function(,)`.

I also tried the non-virtual interface (NVI) method, but it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve the simple code above, in particular, the last line ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible, since there is no guarantee that the object pointed to by a `Base *` is actually an instance of `Derived`.

The most you can do is to use covariant return types for your `clone()` function.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        return new Base(*this);
    };
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Derived* clone() const    // note different return type
                                      // this does override the inherited version
    {
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
};


int main()
{
    Base *b = new Derived;
    Derived *d1 = b->clone();    // this does not work

    Derived *o = new Derived;
    Derived *d = o->clone();    // this works
}
```

If you want to clone from a `Base *` to a `Derived *`, it is necessary to do a runtime check and force a type conversion.

```
Base *b = new Derived;

Base *temp = b->clone();
Derived *d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(temp);
if (d)
{
     // d is actually an instance of Derived so can be used as such
}
else
{
     //  The cloning did not produce a Derived.  Cope with it
}
delete temp;   // this will delete the object pointed to by d, since it is the same object
```

Generally, however, what you are asking is a positive indicator of a flawed design.  In general terms (assuming you need a class hierarchy with a polymorphic base) you need to design the `Base` so its interface (particularly set of virtual functions, which may be specialised by derived classes) are sufficient for all users of the class to do what they need.   All users of `Base` should need is a pointer or reference to `Base` (i.e. a `Base &` or a `Base *`), and there should be no need for them to cast from `Base` to `Derived`.   Look up "Liskov Substitution Principle" for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed a dynamic_cast would solve the problem in two lines, without even using clone(). However, I have different `Derived<T>` and if I use dynamic_cast, I will have to use some if-else, as you do in your code, which I want to avoid. Moreover, the class parameters T, are not known in advance, they are defined at the very beginning by the user with a forward declaration. Therefore, one would have to change the code (the if-else) each time different T are defined. I am looking for some automated method such as the clone().

Comment: @Peter If you're going to delete a derived object through a `Base` pointer, then Base's destructor must be virtual.

Comment: @ChristopheJ.Ortiz if you don't know at runtime that a `Base*` points to a `Derived<T>` but want to get a `Derived<T>*`, then there is simply no way to avoid an if-else check. There is a construct in c++ that can easily solve a changing class parameter at compile time without changing code. It's a template.

Comment: @Chris - what you're asking for is actually a sign of a broken design.   For user:  yes, a virtual destructor is needed.   I've updated my post in response to both.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you should do casting. You could google more about static_Cast and reinterpret_cast. Here's some references : [How to force implicit conversion in polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756993/how-to-force-implicit-conversion-in-polymorphism), [Proper way of casting pointer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578935/proper-way-of-casting-pointer-types)

Comment: The problem could be solved with a dynamic_cast, indeed. But this is not what I want since one must know in advance the type (Derived) to do `dynamic_cast<Derived<T> *>`, as explained in my post. If I take randomly two elements from my `vector<Base *>`, a priori they will be of type `Derived<T1>` and of type `Derived<T2>`, which I do not know. Thus, if I do a dynamic_cast, I'll have to do some if-else to check if the conversion was ok, which I want to avoid.